# Interpreting classification report

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have been working on implementing the KEA supervised approach to keyphrase extraction with 150 documents (100 train and 50 test). The results left me a bit baffled. This is my classification report:

```
           precision    recall  f1-score   support

      0       0.97      1.00      0.98     29118
      1       0.00      0.00      0.00       951

avg / total       0.94      0.97      0.95     30069
```

Which I am interpreting that 1 was never predicted. Do you think this was the case that I do not have enough training data?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not so much that you have enough training data *in general*, but *specifically not enough samples for class 1*. 
 Essentially, there are a few ways you can tackle this problem:

- **Try to increase the number of samples for case 1**: The most obvious answer is also likely not realistic, since you would have probably started with more training data in the first place then. But there are related approaches, namely
- **Data augmentation**: I am not familiar with the specific algorithm, so I cannot say how easy it is in general, but you might add some forms of permutations to you examples that still keep the meaning (i.e. represent the same class), but are different enough to serve as "another training sample".
- **Weighted classes**: Depeneding on the specifics of your learning algorithm, you can often also specify some form of class weights, that allow you to "punish" the algorithm more for misclassifying the class you are interested in.

Generally, this is a really hard task to perform, and it is unlikely that you will suddenly get insanely better results, but these will certainly help to improve your case, and help you better understand what is going wrong in your specific case.
Also note that the more information on your documents, training procedure, etc. you add (it could be a reference/link to the implementation you are using), the likelier it is for you to get a suitable answer.